# Angular: unsubscribe http request

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an array of http requests which uploads big files.

```
const requests = []

requests.push(HttpClient.post())
requests.push(HttpClient.post())
requests.push(HttpClient.post())

concat(...requests).subscribe()
```

I would like to cancel a file upload request for example, I would like to cancel the second file upload request.
How can I do that?

I am using concat here because, requests should be done one after another i.e sequentially.

Comment: If I understand correctly, would you like to close all the observables if one of them errors out?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the result request, for example like this:

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
    private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public doRequests() {
        const requests = []

        requests.push(this.http.post())
        requests.push(this.http.post())
        requests.push(this.http.post())

        return concat(...requests).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe()
    }

    public cancelRequests() {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will cancel all the requests? I just want to cancel one or two requests

Comment: Yes, this will cancel all still running requests. I'm not sure i understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subject that emits the index of the request you want cancelled. So that might look something like this:

```ts
const cancel$ = new Subject<number>();

const requests = Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(
  (_,i) => HttpClient.post().pipe(
    takeUntil(cancel$.pipe(
      filter(v => v === i)
    ))
  )
);

concat(...requests).subscribe();

// cancel the second request.
cancel$.next(1);
```